# iOS: how do I wait until app fully loads to begin animation?

Tags: iphone, ios, loading, uiviewanimation

I have a first-screen `UIView` animation that simulates the view falling to the ground and bouncing. It is supposed to fall from the top of the screen. Instead, when the app loads, it's already hit the ground.

When running on the iPhone simulator, or as part of a build directly from `Xcode` live to the phone, it works perfectly: the app loads and then the animation happens.

But when launching the app cold, that is, terminating it on the phone from the app switcher and then starting it up again, the app loads and the animation is almost totally complete (some bouncing still happens, which is how I know it doesn't just skip the animation altogether).

I can only assume that I need some sort of method that waits until the screen/app is fully loaded to start the animation. Any pointers on this?

Comment: Which function are you calling your code in? Can you post up some sample code please.

Comment: Cannot post sample code. I am calling it from viewDidLoad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can add the animation code in the method

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

of your first ViewController, so the animation will be performed only if the view is displayed

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the status of Your animation when Your app goes in background than resume the state of your animation when your app come in foreground.
You can use [self perform selector: withdelay:] method to call the method that responsible for animation by specifying NSTimeInterval in seconds.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(methodName:) withDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: According to the original question the app is launching fresh not returning from the background so this solution will not work